# Display particular word on some condition Eval Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval, repeater

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLeaveStatus" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("Leave_Status").ToString() == 'A' ? 'Approved' : 'Applied' %>'></asp:Label>
```

Condition to display a particular word in the `GridView` on some condition

Could some thing like this work on `Gridview`

**I get an error Server Tag not well formed**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLeaveStatus" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("Leave_Status").ToString() .Equals ( "A") ? "Approved" : "Applied" %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code:

```
<% if(Eval("Leave_Status").ToString() == "A"{%>

<asp:Label ID="lblLeaveStatus" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Approved"></asp:Label>

<%}
else {
%>
<asp:Label ID="lblLeaveStatus" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Applied"></asp:Label>

<%}%>
```

Comment: Chaange to    <% if(Eval("Leave_Status").ToString() == "A"){%>

Comment: -1 The issue was OP had the wrong quotes (single quotes) on the ternary operator string values, which is inside of the server code tags <% %>, and therefore must use double quotes. Otherwise his code was just fine. Rewriting as this answer suggests reminds me of Classic ASP, not ASP.net.