# syntax error for ASP.NET onclick

Tags: asp.net

I am modifying an asp.net page which has the following code:

```
<input type="button" id="room22SendEmail" name="room22SendEmail" value="Send" onclick="SendEmail('<%=mainValue%>');"/>
```

but there is an error after "SendMail('<%.." unterminated string constant. If I remove the single quotes I get a syntax error.

Whether it is

```
onclick="SendEmail(<%=#mainValue%>");'>
```

or

```
onclick="SendEmail(<%=mainValue%>");'>
```

I get the syntax error in the same places, marking the ( and )

Comment: Change the `=` character for `#` as you can see in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15426037)

Comment: Whether it is onclick="SendEmail(<%=#mainValue%>");'> or onclick="SendEmail(<%=mainValue%>");'> I get the syntax error in the same places, marking the ( and ).

Comment: Update your question instead put a comment _this will be useful for other members of StackOverflow_

Comment: @Ron He said *change*. Not *add*. Thus you should try `onclick="SendEmail('<%# mainValue%>');'>`

Comment: I tried that. onclick="SendEmail('<%# mainValue%>');"/>  At the ( the error is ") expected" and at the closing ) the error is "unterminated string constant"

Comment: Try `onclick='SendEmail(<%="mainValue"%>');'> `. I noticed when you update you question, you putted `onclick="SendEmail(<%=#mainValue%>");'> ` **no**, use instead a single character `=` or `#`. Also, did you have other controls with similar code in your asp.net page?

Comment: First there are no other controls with similar code. I tried this: `onclick='SendEmail();'/>` (i.e., nothing inside the () ) and that doesn't cause any syntax errors. However `onclick="SendEmail(<%= %>;">` causes a syntax error at the first ( . Same with replacing = with #. Or putting an expression inside (mainValue).

Comment: This problem still occurs. The problem seems to be how I escape (?) the ( ) in the code. There is nothing similar anywhere else in the code. I've looked on the web but without success.